# Block/Blur Screenshot IOS React-Native

Tags: react-native

Using React-Native I can not block the screenshot. I need to block or blur the screen for IOs. I've tried several things but I could not. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: This library prevents screenshots on iOS and Android: https://github.com/hawkup/react-native-prevent-screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I've built a library that could help you achieve this in React-Native. Give it a try:

`yarn add react-native-screenguard`

`npm i --save react-native-screenguard`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screenguard

Remember to check out for the `Post install for Android` on `README.md` to set up a little bit on Android, as it might not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

i think this libary should be helping https://github.com/hawkup/react-native-prevent-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Currently the best method to do prevention in IOS is using https://screenshieldkit.com/

However, I created a lib to block screenshot (on android) and detect screenshot action on IOS.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-screenshot-prevention